# Can I configure the dictionary language used by the spellcheck attribute on my form elements?

Tags: html, input, textarea, lang, spelling

I need to add the `spellcheck` attribute to a few `<textarea>` and `<input>` elements. My question is: *"Is the version of English that* `spellcheck` *adheres to configurable?"* I'm in Australia and we use British English. My understanding is that the spellchecker is configured to American English by default.

Does it have anything to do with the `lang` attribute that is initially set on the `html` element?

Comment: Attributes and tags are not the same thing. Please don't conflate them.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Good pick up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe I have sourced an answer to this question and been schooled on English in the process.

The W3C reference of [language codes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp) would suggest that the version of English is not configurable. However, I found a more detailed [W3C Working Group Note](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H57.html) that reads as follows:

> *Note 2:* Allowed values for the lang and xml:lang attributes are indicated in the resources referenced below. Language tags use a primary code to indicate the language, and optional subcodes (separated by hyphen characters) to indicate variants of the language. For instance, English is indicated with the primary code "en"; British English and American English can be distinguished by using "en-GB" and "en-US", respectively. Use of the primary code is important for this technique. Use of subcodes is optional but may be helpful in certain circumstances.

Here is a full list of subcodes: [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2).

This means that any one of the following values are technically valid; `lang="en-AU"`, `lang="en-GB"` and `lang="en-US"`.

I ran two tests to determine how `spellcheck` behaved with these language subcodes (see snippet). I ran these tests on *macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.2* in Safari Version 11.0.2, *Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132* and *Firefox Version 57.0.4* and had mixed results.

**None** of the browsers I tested seemed to be impacted by the `lang` attribute declarations made to various elements. I tested with dictionaries turned on and off at a system level.

I tested Safari and Chrome first and had the same result:
[image]

I then tested Firefox and had this result:
[image]

So in summation: "Yes" the version of English is configurable when using the `lang` attribute. "No", `spellcheck` doesn't seem to be configurable to the language you declare with the `lang` attribute, but to the browser's configured version of English instead.

I hope this answer helps somebody else.

```html
<!-- Test #1 -->
<textarea lang="en-AU" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
<textarea lang="en-GB" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
<textarea lang="en-US" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
<div contenteditable="true" lang="en-AU" spellcheck="true">insert spelling</div>
<div contenteditable="true" lang="en-GB" spellcheck="true">insert spelling</div>
<div contenteditable="true" lang="en-US" spellcheck="true">insert spelling</div>
```

```html
<!-- Test #2 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-AU">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <textarea spellcheck="true"></textarea>
 <div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true">insert spelling</div>
</body>
</html>
```